# Why is the following matrix numerically unstable?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

I am trying to perform LU Decomposition on the following n-dimensional square matrix

$$ C = [c_{ij}], \ c_{ij} = \frac{1}{i + j - 1}, \ i,j = 1, ..., n \ , $$

and use it to solve linear systems. But even using a small $n$ such as $n = 5$ provides an inaccurate solution to a linear system, so I tried to find its condition number from $n = 1, ...., 10$ to see if the matrix is the reason for such numerical inaccuracy. Using Python's `numpy.linalg.cond` with Frobenius norm as its matrix norm, I got the following result:

$$
\begin{array}[c|c]
nn & \text{condition number} \\
1 & 1.0 \\
2 & 19.333333333333336 \\
3 & 526.1588210797212 \\
4 & 15613.793559642412 \\
5 & 480849.11699558934 \\
6 & 15118987.131683761 \\
7 & 481747254.15379786 \\
8 & 15493617537.994034 \\
9 & 501730274777.0853 \\
10 & 16332405266874.348 \\
\end{array}
$$

Clearly, $C$ is an ill-conditioned matrix. But why? Is it because as $n$ gets larger, the entries of $C$ approaches zero? Is this always the case with rational functions where the denominator increases faster compared to the numerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that the entries approach $0$, it's that they approach $0$ in a very regular way, so that the last row is very nearly a linear combination of the other rows.

Look up: [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix)

Comment: Do you know a quick analysis of the condition number of the Hilbert matrix? It does not have give the right complexity, but I would like to do better than just linear growth. I am hoping for something that can be formulated as a few sentences when presenting the Hilbert matrix as one of several test matrices. The intended audience does not have an extensive background in analysis.